# Get numbers from several text fields with $_POST?

Tags: php

i'm trying to store a given time in my database:

I have 2 text fields with input hours and minutes - hh:mm

I need these values to be merged together in one variable like this:

```
$time = hhmm00
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to post your code?

Comment: This is solved! Thanks all.
JUst need to wait 4 more minutes to mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the work.

```
$time = $_POST['hours'] . $_POST['minutes'] . "00";
```

Fromthere you see how you could do:

```
$time = $_POST['hours'] . ':' . $_POST['minutes'] . ":00";//outputs 12:12:00
```

Comment: Don't forget to append ."00" to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
echo "{$_POST['hours']}:{$_POST['minutes']}:00";
```